# How do I get string from the address of char*?

Tags: c, char

```
char *p = "cat";
char a = *p;
printf("%c", &a);
```

The code above doesn't working. How do I get string data "cat" from pointer *p and store it at char a? Statement 'char *p = "cat";' should not be changed.

Comment: `printf("%c", &a)` -> `printf("%c", a)`. Former does not make sense, you tell printf you're providing a `char` but you _actually_ provide the _memory address_ of a `char`. Or maybe you just want `printf("%s", p);`. The question is quite unclear. What output do you expect?

Comment: I want string "cat" is stored at a and print it. So output that I want is"cat".

Comment: Then you need `printf("%s", p);`. It should be explained in details in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: Then how do I store string "cat" into char a?

Comment: `a` can only contain a single character, not an entire string of characters. After `char a = *p;`, `a` contains the character `'c'`. I suggest you read the chapter dealing with strings in your learning material.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer p in your code points to the first value of the string which is c. So when you assign the value at p to a you will get the character ‘c’ stored in a. But then you in the last line of your code you wrote &a which refers to the address of a which will be a garbage value and won’t give any results. Alternatively if you would have written *p or a instead of &a you would have gotten ‘c’ as the result.

Comment: I learned that char* p has address of "c", which is the first letter of "cat". What I want to do is to get string "cat" from pointer p and then store that string "cat" into char a.

Comment: A string is an array of chars

Comment: You can't save a string in a char. You need to have firstly declare a as a string and then use the command "strcpy" under the header file #include<string.h>. Otherwise, if you want to print "cat" using only *p, then you can use a simple while loop and keep on incrementing the pointer until it reaches the end.

Answer (score 1):

As above: A char can store only one character. A string is an array of characters ending with '\0'. So loop through the string and recover the characters until the termination '\0' is found.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char *p = "cat";

    int i = 0; char a[100];

    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        a[i] = *p;
        i ++; 
        p += 1;
    }
    a[i] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: cat

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really helped me a lot! This is great solution. Thanks for your help again!